# Angular 2 http.post() is not sending the request

Tags: angular, angular2-http

When I make a post request the angular 2 http is not sending this request

```
this.http.post(this.adminUsersControllerRoute, JSON.stringify(user), this.getRequestOptions())
```

the http post is not sent to the server but if I make the request like this

```
this.http.post(this.adminUsersControllerRoute, JSON.stringify(user), this.getRequestOptions()).subscribe(r=>{});
```

Is this intended and if it is can someone explain me why ? Or it is a bug ?

Answer (score 299, accepted):

Since the `post` method of the `Http` class returns an observable you need to call `subscribe()` to execute its initialization processing. Observables are lazy.

You should have a look at this video for more details:

- https://egghead.io/lessons/rxjs-rxjs-observables-vs-promises

Comment: @Thiery Can't watch the video, since it's for members only

Comment: Always [I forget this].

Answer (score 82):

You *must subscribe* to the returned observable if you want the call to execute.

See also the following angular documentation "[Communicating with backend services using HTTP](https://angular.io/guide/http#starting-the-request)".

> #### Starting the request
>
> For all [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) methods, the method doesn't begin its HTTP request until you call `subscribe()` on the observable the method returns.
>
> This is true for *all* [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) *methods*.
>
> > You should always unsubscribe from an observable when a component is destroyed.
>
> All observables returned from [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) methods are *cold* by design.
> Execution of the HTTP request is *deferred*, letting you extend the observable with additional operations such as  `tap` and `catchError` before anything actually happens.
>
> Calling `subscribe()` triggers execution of the observable and causes [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) to compose and send the HTTP request to the server.
>
> Think of these observables as *blueprints* for actual HTTP requests.
>
> > In fact, each `subscribe()` initiates a separate, independent execution of the observable.
> > Subscribing twice results in two HTTP requests.
> >
> > ```js
> > const req = http.get&lt;Heroes&gt;('/api/heroes');
> > // 0 requests made - .subscribe() not called.
> > req.subscribe();
> > // 1 request made.
> > req.subscribe();
> > // 2 requests made.
> > ```

On a related note: The [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) subscribes (and unsubscribes) for you automatically.

Answer (score 48):

Get method doesn't require to use the subscribe method but post method requires the subscribe. Get and post sample codes are below.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'
import { Post } from './model/post'
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

@Component({
    templateUrl: './test.html',
    selector: 'test'
})
export class NgFor implements OnInit {

    posts: Observable<Post[]>
    model: Post = new Post()

    /**
     *
     */
    constructor(private http: Http) {

    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.list()
    }

    private list(){
        this.posts = this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/posts").map((val, i) => <Post[]>val.json())
    }

    public addNewRecord(){
        let bodyString = JSON.stringify(this.model); // Stringify payload
        let headers      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); // ... Set content type to JSON
        let options       = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option

        this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/posts", this.model, options) // ...using post request
                         .map(res => res.json()) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
                         .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')) //...errors if
                         .subscribe();
    }
}
```