# Typescript Angular 2 Http post to C# MVC

Tags: c#, angularjs, typescript

Trying to pass a payload via Typescript service to an http.post

My .ts code:

```
saveEdits(body: Object): Observable<Animal[]> {
    let bodyString = JSON.stringify(body); 
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); 
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 

    return this.http.post(this.UrlToEdit, body, options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .catch((error: any) => console.log("Edited value did not been saved"));
}
```

Mention that

```
private UrlToEdit = '/Home/Edit';
```

Although the value is up to the service, C# controller not seems to fire up.. An here its code:

```
[HttpPost]
public  async Task<Boolean> Edit([Bind(Include = "animalID,animalName,animalHabitat,animalClass")] Animal animal)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      db.Entry(animal).State = EntityState.Modified;
      await db.SaveChangesAsync();
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Could you ensure data presents in Fiddler? Could you show payload inside Fiddler and  **Animal** class?

Comment: Data do present to the Fiddler.
Although, class is 
`export class Animal {
    animalID: number;
    animalName: string;
    animalHabitat: string;
    animalClass: string;
}`

Comment: Could you replace `[Bind(Include = "animalID,...,animalClass")]` with `[FromBody]`, and try again?

Comment: Confused about the [FromBody]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know how your whole site is working but maybe this helps you:

First i see an error in your code, you should pass the **bodyString**  in the post not the body

```
return this.http.post(this.UrlToEdit, bodyString, options)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .catch((error: any) => console.log("Edited value did not been saved"));
```

Second post returns an Observable so the post is executed when something subscribes to the observable like this

```
//...somewhere in your code ...
service.saveEdits(body).subscribe((animals: Animal[]) => console.log(animals));
```

Also open chrome debugger (or whatever browser you use) and see in the network tab if the post is executed and if there is any error

I hope this helps you

Comment: This is actually the answer(very very similar)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208732/angular-2-http-post-is-not-sending-the-request

Thank you for taking the time!