# Post data to API with or without subscribe

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular-httpclient

In Angular 7 I am getting and posting data from an API.

**GET**

- To get data I am using an Observable (posts$) and pipe / map;
- I am using async in the Component HTML and **not using Subscribe**;
- This is the approach I have seen recently including in Angular docs.

**POST**

- The Service Post method also returns data:
  Possible validation errors or the ID of the created Post.
  I need to get any of them when they are returned by the API.

However, when calling the service to POST the following does nothing:

```
this.postService.addPost(model).pipe();
```

Unless I use `subscribe` as follows:

```
this.postService.addPost(model).pipe().subscribe();
```

**Question**
How would I post to the API without using subscribe? And does it make sense?

**Component**

```
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {

  posts$: Observable<GetPostsModel[]>;

  constructor(private postService: PostService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.posts$ = this.getPosts();
  }

  addPost(model: AddPostModel) {

    this.postService.addPost(model).pipe().subscribe();

  }

  getPosts(): Observable<GetPostsModel[]> {

    return this.postService.getPosts().pipe(

      map((response: GetPostsResponse) => 

        return {
          // Map Response to GetPostsModel here 
        };

      }));

  }

}
```

**Service**

```
export class PostService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public addPost(model: AddPostModel): Observable<AddPostResponse>> {

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

    return this.httpClient.post<AddPostResponse>>('posts', model, { headers: headers });

  }

  public getPosts(): Observable<GetPostsResponse>> {
    return this.httpClient.get<GetPostsResponse>>('posts');
  }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 http.post() is not sending the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208732/angular-2-http-post-is-not-sending-the-request)

Comment: You need to use subscribe on an observable. "An Observable instance begins publishing values only when someone subscribes to it" - https://angular.io/guide/observables#subscribing

Comment: One way would be to use RxJS connectable observables.

Answer (score 4):

> How would I post to the API without using subscribe?

You can't, you must always subscribe. If you do not care about the result you do not have to supply a callback. This is perfectly valid:

```
this.postService.addPost(model).subscribe();
```

*side note: you do not need an empty `pipe` in this case*

See also [Angular 2 http.post() is not sending the request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36208732/1260204) and [HttpClient - Always subscribe!](https://angular.io/guide/http#always-subscribe) documentation.

> ### Always subscribe!
>
> An `HttpClient` method does not begin its HTTP request until you call subscribe() on the observable returned by that method. This is true for all `HttpClient` methods.

Answer (score 1):

The Observable returned by any of the Http operations (get/post/put/etc) *require* a subscription.

But in some cases, Angular *automatically* handles that subscription for you.

For example:

- Using an async pipe will automatically subscribe to the returned observable.
- Using a route resolver will automatically subscribe to the returned observable.

In every other case, such as your Post example, you need to subscribe.

**UPDATE**

You only need to add the `pipe` if you need to pipe the response through a set of operators. Normally, you would at least want the `catchError` operator. I often add `tap` during development just for debugging purposes, but it is not necessary.

Here is an example of one of my Post operations:

```
  createProduct(product: Product): Observable<Product> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    return this.http.post<Product>(this.productsUrl, product, { headers: headers })
      .pipe(
        tap(data => console.log('createProduct: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

I don't often see the use of the `pipe` in the client code. For "separation of concerns", normally the data mapping/manipulation is done in the service ... unless there is something component-unique that you need to do.

But just this:

```
this.postService.addPost(model).pipe().subscribe();
```

Piping without piping the response through some operators doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation ... Is there any advantage of using pipe in this.postService.addPost(model).pipe().subscribe()? I mean, I could simply use map() and catch error inside subscribe? Or should I use pipe() and in there use map and catchError() and just call subscribe() at the end?