# Sending POST or GET request from Angular project to Python server

Tags: python, angular, post, get

I made a little server with http.server python library.

```
import http.server
import socketserver

class  SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        print("get")

    def do_POST(self):
        print("post")
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        msg = self.rfile.read(content_length).decode('utf-8')
        print(msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PORT = 8080
    Handler = SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
    with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
        print("serving at port", PORT)
        try:
            httpd.serve_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("-- stop --")
            exit()
```

I tested it with a simple python script

```
import socket

def mypost():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(("localhost", 8080))
    txt = "1234"
    post = "POST /test.txt HTTP/1.0\nContent-Length: " + str(len(txt)) + "\nContent-Type: plain/text\n\n" + txt
    s.send(post.encode())

def myget():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(("localhost", 8080))
    post = "GET HTTP/1.0"
    s.send(post.encode())
```

Get and post are both receive by the server.
Then I want to send the requests with my angular project.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'srp-send-request',
  template: `
  <button  (click)="postMsg()">RUN</button >
  `,
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class SendRequestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  public postMsg() {
    var url = 'http://localhost:8080';
    var msg = "1234";
    var option = {'Content-Length' : msg.length, 'Content-Type': 'plain/text', 'body' : msg};
    var ret = this.http.get<any>('localhost:8080');
    var ret = this.http.request('POST', url, option);
    console.log(ret);
  }
}
```

I can click on the button but the server receive nothing.
I am new to Angular so I don't now what I done wrong. Are my request well formated ?

Comment: from angular site use WebSocket to call socket base API

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 http.post() is not sending the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208732/angular-2-http-post-is-not-sending-the-request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, both Angular's `HttpClient` `get` and `post` methods return an `Observable` object that you have to subscribe to, in order to get the data sent by the server.

```js
public postMsg() {
    var url = 'http://localhost:8080';
    var msg = "1234";
    var option = {'Content-Length' : msg.length, 'Content-Type': 'plain/text', 'body' : msg};
    this.http.get<any>('localhost:8080').subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
    this.http.request('POST', url, option).subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
  }
```

The [http guide](https://angular.io/guide/http) of the Angular website is fairly complete and covers lots of topics, from making GET, POST,... requests, handling the responses, intercepting, incoming and outgoing queries...

Comment: Thanks, I got a Cross origin requests error now but it acualy do something ^^

Comment: Oh yeah, makes sense. I suppose your Angular server is running on `localhost:4200` while your python one is on `localhost:8080`? You should add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` HTTP header, but I'm not sure I know in which request to add it though... ^^'

Comment: Oh no, never mind, it work well with my post request. The get was just for testing purpose so it is ok ^^